# Make WordPress plugin to load after document.ready

Tags: wordpress

I am having a problem with WordPress plugin called Photo Final Tiles Grid Gallery- on some devices the gallery loads up okay, but on some devices (mostly mobile) it doesn't load up at all.

This is the error I am getting on some devices:
[image]

Is there any way to make this plugin load after document.ready?

Comment: It is better to consult the plugin developers for such issue as they can give a very accurate answer.

Comment: They don't offer any support for free version of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not load plugin after `document.ready`, because plugin loaded in PHP and `document.ready` is JavaScript event.

The solution for your problem is edit the finalTilesGalley.js by adding the code that check if the object exists before trying to get width of this object.

Example:

```
if( typeof obj != 'undefined' ){
    width = obj.width();
}
```

Comment: If I change finalTilesGalley.js file then all changes will be gone after I update the plugin :/.

Comment: Exactly. But it will resolve the problem at the moment.